# Magento 2 : How to run 2 cron jobs at the same time?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cronjobs

In my crontab.xml I have 2 different cron jobs which are invoking 2 different methods scheduled to run on the minute. When I do the command "bin/magento cron:run" only one job is running. Below is my crontab.xml file
How do I get both jobs running at the same time?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default">
    <job name="jAssign_cronjob" instance="Mobileplans\Cron\Jivetel" method="assignForwarding">
        <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
    <job name="jRemove_cronjob" instance="Mobileplans\Cron\Jivetel" method="removeForwarding">
        <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work.

Although have you tried a different group?

```
<config>
    <group id="default">
        <job name="<job_1_name>" instance="<classpath>" method="<method_name>">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
    <group id="index">
        <job name="<job_2_name>" instance="<classpath>" method="<method_name>">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked. But I was still wondering why my code wasn't working. So I tried my code again and it worked! I am so confused! Why does it work only sometimes?

Comment: Not sure sorry. Should have worked first time.